# Geth Chain Config. Is it possible to get the node ChainConfig (Constantinople: blocknumber, ...) from geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardforks, configuration

Is it possible to get the node ChainConfig (with hardforks blocks numbers activation like Constantinople: blocknumber ...) from the geth console?

Is geth using only ChainConfig from genesis.json or is it a way to update ChainConfig and add new hardforks block numbers when it's necessary?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get `ChainConfig` struct from console because there is no client implementation for that. This is because these values are fixed (constants) and only change by network, so nobody would ask for them on regular basis (using console or RPC).

If you need to get these constants for any network you can get it from sources:

```
MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
    ChainID:                       big.NewInt(1),
    HomesteadBlock:                big.NewInt(1_150_000),
    DAOForkBlock:                  big.NewInt(1_920_000),
    DAOForkSupport:                true,
    EIP150Block:                   big.NewInt(2_463_000),
    EIP150Hash:                    common.HexToHash("0x2086799aeebeae135c246c65021c82b4e15a2c451340993aacfd2751886514f0"),
    EIP155Block:                   big.NewInt(2_675_000),
    EIP158Block:                   big.NewInt(2_675_000),
    ByzantiumBlock:                big.NewInt(4_370_000),
    ConstantinopleBlock:           big.NewInt(7_280_000),
    PetersburgBlock:               big.NewInt(7_280_000),
    IstanbulBlock:                 big.NewInt(9_069_000),
    MuirGlacierBlock:              big.NewInt(9_200_000),
    BerlinBlock:                   big.NewInt(12_244_000),
    LondonBlock:                   big.NewInt(12_965_000),
    ArrowGlacierBlock:             big.NewInt(13_773_000),
    GrayGlacierBlock:              big.NewInt(15_050_000),
    TerminalTotalDifficulty:       MainnetTerminalTotalDifficulty, // 58_750_000_000_000_000_000_000
    TerminalTotalDifficultyPassed: true,
    Ethash:                        new(EthashConfig),
}
```

This is the file where they are published:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/config.go